# Blender - Apollonian Gasket with Geometry Nodes

Tags: blender

I am looking into fractals with Blender.

Would like to make an Apollonian Gasket, I believe it's possible with geometry nodes.

I have found some tutorials on creating fractals with Blender Geo Nodes, but not this one..

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

[image]

Thanks!